# mod_rewrite understanding sub-directories whilst passing $_GET value server issue?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

This may well be a server config issue; or simply a blindly obvious reason I'm missing...

Pre mod_rewrite URL:

```
www.example.com/subfolder/index.php?userName=x
```

The devised mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/[^/]([\w]*)$ /subfolder/index.php?userName=$1 [L]
```

It is my understanding that the above should allow navigation to: `www.example.com/subfolder/x`. However this causes a 404 error.

Rewrites without the sub-folder work fine; it is only when adding the subfoler to the mix things fall to put.

Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead (works OK for me):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/([^/]+)$ /subfolder/index.php?userName=$1 [L]
```

**NOTE:**

This rule is to be placed in .htaccess. If placed in server config / virtual host context, some small tweaking will be required.

Comment: Hi @LazyOne works perfectly - Thank you so much; your efforts hardly reflect your username. Thanks again